# Recherche d'un verbe signifiant « rendre répétable »

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je recherche un mot, de préférence un verbe, pour exprimer l'idée de « rendre répétable » ou « rendre plus régulier ».
Dans le contexte, il s'agît de proposer des outils qui automatisent certaines tâches. Par conséquent, je souhaite mettre en avant le fait que l'on va pouvoir répéter ces tâches plus régulièrement qu'auparavant.

J'en suis arrivé à employer le terme « Régulariser » dans son sens premier (rendre plus régulier) mais je crains que cela soit mal compris et interprété par erreur comme « rendre conforme ».

Auriez-vous un verbe ou une expression plus pertinente ?

Comment: Je ne comprend pas l'idée. Est-ce que l'action est d'avoir mis en place l'automatisation (genre installé Jenkins), ou est-ce que vous avez adapté les taches, pour qu'elles soient toutes "régulières" et donc automatisable via Jenkins ?

Comment: Je liste les avantages d'une telle solution (gagner du temps, avoir des indicateurs supplémentaires...) 
Je cherche donc à exprimer que, une fois les tâches automatisées, on va pouvoir les rejouer beaucoup plus souvent car on les a rendu reproductible, répétable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Régulariser* ne convient pas du tout.** Il est habituellement employé pour signifier corriger quelque chose qui n'était pas régulier (pas normal, pas légal), très souvent employé comme *régulariser un dossier, une situation*.

**Pour rendre répétable:**

- *Automatiser* est le terme le mieux compris pour le sens demandé.

La principale notion est la répétitivité - dans le sens *refaire la même chose* -.

La régularité n'est plus nécessairement déterminée: c'est une définition vieillote du Grand Robert.

- D'autres termes peuvent être employés dans des contextes particuliers mais n'ont pas forcément le même sens:

  - *mécaniser* est un terme proche, avec une spécialisation en terme d'outil (mécanique), et moins le sens de répétitivité.
  - *outiller* est moins fort en terme de répétition, mais le sens est souvent implicite. Il est aussi beaucoup moins spécialisé que *mécaniser*. L'outil peut être quelconque: il peut s'agir d'une méthode, de pratiques. On a aussi *instrumenter*, plus raffiné (un thermomètre opposé à un marteau).
  - *industrialiser* suppose un contexte professionnel. On dit aussi *professionnaliser*. Mais cela ne passe pas forcément par une automatisation, plutôt une notion de procédures (ce qui conduit à *formaliser*, voire le terme assez affreux *procédurer*).

**Pour rendre régulier:**

Le sens recherché est différent. Il ne s'agit plus forcédent de procéder de la même manière, mais de le refaire dans le temps. Je ne vois pas de verbe bien précis (*répéter* veut aussi dire cela - sic -), mais on peut marquer la cadence par un adverbe: exécuter *quotidiennement*, *mensuellement*, *annuellement*, etc.

Pour être impératif, on peut dire *séquencer*, *rythmer*, *cadencer* (les tâches), qui peuvent s'appliquer à des travaux rapprochés, à la chaîne.

*Planifier* est un terme plus général qui indique cette notion de dates fixées ou à fixer.

Answer (score 6):

Il me semble que dans ce cas on utilise simplement le verbe **automatiser**.

La définition du Grand Robert pour automatiser:

> Rendre automatique.

Et pour automatique:

> Qui s'accomplit avec une régularité déterminée.
>   Qui doit forcément se produire.

Donc, automatiser une tâche, la rendre automatique avec une régularité déterminée.

Answer (score 4):

Voici quelques suggestions : uniformiser, standardiser, normaliser.

Comment: On peut ajouter "formaliser" lorsqu'il s'agit de décrire, puis de mettre en oeuvre les procédures propres à chaque tâche.

Answer (score 4):

En utilisant des outils tels que [Jenkins](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28logiciel%29), on parle d'**intégration continue** ou d'**automatisation** de tâche. On peut donc dire que la tâche est **automatisable**, et le fait d'avoir **automatisé** cette tâche la rend plus rapide, plus fiable, plus pratique.

En général, cela concerne les déploiements sur une machine, ainsi que le lancement des tests unitaires.

Answer (score 3):

S'il s'agit d'adapter un procédé de fabrication pour faire en sorte qu'il soit exécuté par des machines, je propose:

> industrialiser

Answer (score 1):

Ça ne s’agit pas d’un seul mot [mais à la rigueur, vos exemples donnés en commentaire  (« gagner du temps [et] avoir des indicateurs supplémentaires ») ne le sont pas non plus], mais si vous avez assez d’espace pour plusieurs mots peut-être vous pourriez considérer :

> [automatiser et] **[faciliter les tâches
>   répétitives](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/faciliter+les+t%C3%A2ches+r%C3%A9p%C3%A9titives.html)**
>   .

(Mais attention, l’exemple donné par « Linguee » est « non révisé » et je ne suis pas natif)